# Editing external CSS stylesheet with a Firefox add-on

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm writing a Firefox add-on using the SDK. When a page is loaded, I want to edit both the DOM and the external CSS.

I use pagemod to edit the DOM, so I tried editing the CSS at the same time. But the stylesheets (given by `documents.styleSheets`) are external, so trying to look at their `cssRules` is a SecurityError.

The [pagemod manual](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod) says scripts are attached to documents loaded in tabs. I assume this means I can't attach the edition script directly to the CSS sheet.

So I need a different SDK API, that listens for loading of CSS sheets, and can edit them. Nothing in the [list of APIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) looks obviously relevant.

Where should I look?

Comment: `iniDOMUtils` module is the source of all things css related, you can hack up and get anything with this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Reference/Interface/inIDOMUtils#getCSSStyleRules%28%29

Comment: Why not add your own CSS that overrides the existing stylesheets?

Comment: @Bwaxxlo Because I need the cssRules to know which classes I need to modify.